# There is no /proc/bus/usb directory

Tags: linux, usb, devices, proc

I'm running a centos VM on ESXi.

Does the /proc/bus/usb directory not show up until a USB device is connected?

I just added a USB controller to the VM (it previously had non) and ran lsusb:

```
$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/6p, 480M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/7p, 12M
```

Ok so I see that controller I just added, but I don't see anything under /proc/bus/usb.

```
$ ls /proc/bus/
input  pci
```

If I where to connect a usb device would /proc/bus/usb/ appear? I was reading that Linux provides a usb filesystem that appears as part of /proc.

Just curious about how this works.